# Function createInterface with readline

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I want to create a communication between two clients using the matrix server, and the readline package.

I create a customer :

```
var myUserId = "@nina:my.domain.name";
var myAccessToken = "nina";
var sdk = require("matrix-js-sdk");
var clc = require("cli-color");
var matrixClient = sdk.createClient({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8448",
  idBaseUrl: "https://vector.im",
  accessToken: myAccessToken,
  userId: myUserId
});
```

And I create an interface :

```
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  completer: completer
});
rl.setPrompt("$ ");`
```

I get this error : ERROR TypeError: `readline.createInterface is not a function`

Comment: Which version of node do you use? Do you have `readline` package installed from npm?

Comment: @hsz
I have this : `@types/node": "~6.0.60",` `"ts-node": "~3.0.4",` and `"readline": "^1.3.0",`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment - you have installed:

```
"@types/node": "~6.0.60"
"ts-node": "~3.0.4"
"readline": "^1.3.0"
```

`readline` package does not contain `createInterface` method.
Native nodejs also contain package called `readline` which is covered by the one prom npm repository.

You should simply uninstall `readline`, so the native node package will be used.

Comment: I still have an error after uninstalling Readline. He puts this mistake `Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,`on this line `var readline = require("readline");` Should I do something ?